# Force a button to be pressed before executing macro

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I have in excel a button panel created where each button has a macro assigned to it that increments the value 1 to 1.

I would like to add 3 new buttons where each time I press one of the buttons already created, it forces me to press one of those three before the increment.

Those 3 new buttons would detail if the action of the rest of the buttons happens if the team is losing, drawing or winning.

Case: Press on the first red one "IZQUIERDA" and then be forced to press on one of the 3 to be created before the macro that is on "IZQUIERDA" makes the increment.

This is the panel actually. I know how to created but not the VBA necessary to do it.

[image: Actual panel]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not finding anything on the internet on how to fix this.

The only way I have thought of would be to create 3 new buttons for each button created with each case but I don't know if there is something more efficient. @MaciejLos

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand you well...

Supose, you have a macro called:

```
Private Sub IZQUIERDA_Button_Click()
  'here is the code you use to increment value.
End Sub
```

So, if you want to call the other macro before increment

```
Private Sub IZQUIERDA_Button_Click()
  Call TheOtherMacroName_Here
  'then the code you use to increment value.
End Sub
```

More at: [Call statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/call-statement)

If this does not meet your criteria, please, let me know.

Comment: I don't think I explained it well yesterday. I need the increment to be made when 2 buttons are pressed in a row. The first one will be one of the ones shown in the image and the second one of the three to be created.

I press a red button for example, then one of the three to create and then the increment should be done @maciej Los

Answer (score 0):

You could put the 3 buttons on another form and code them

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.result = "Losing"
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    UserForm1.result = "Draw"
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    UserForm1.result = "Winning"
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

and add a Public variable to the first form and add some code to show the 2nd form

```vb
Option Explicit
Public result
Private Sub IZQUIERDA_Click()
   result = ""
   UserForm2.Show
   MsgBox "Team is " & result
   
   ' rest macro
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think I explained it well yesterday. I need the increment to be made when 2 buttons are pressed in a row. The first one will be one of the ones shown in the image and the second one of the three to be created.

I press a red button for example, then one of the three to create and then the increment should be done. @CDP1802

Comment: @Carlos When you press the IZQUIERDA button then a second form shows with 3 buttons on. When you press one of those buttons the form closes and the original IZQUIERDA macro continues with the incrementing. You repeat the lines `result = "": UserForm2.Show` in each on your button macro.